# Databricks and s3 data

Tags: amazon-s3, databricks

How to mount an S3 bucket on Databricks with Python?

```
access_key = dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "aws", key = "my key")
secret_key = dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "aws", key = "my key")
encoded_secret_key = secret_key.replace("/", "%2F")

aws_bucket_name = "bengali-ai"
mount_name = "bengali"
dbutils.fs.mount("s3a://%s:%s@%s" % (access_key, encoded_secret_key, aws_bucket_name), "/mnt/%s" % mount_name)
```

I got the error:

> Secret does not exist with scope: aws and key: my aws access key

Answer (score 0):

You first have to set up your secrets - scope and key

```
databricks secrets put --scope <scope-name> --key <key-name>
```